# Flutter Edit List Item

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a question in my flutter dart script, this my script:

```
List<ReplyTile> replytile = new List<ReplyTile>();

replytile.add(
    new ReplyTile(
        member_photo: "photo",
        member_id: "001",
        date: "01-01-2018",
        member_name: "Denis",
        id: "001",
        text: "hallo.."
    )
);
```

My question is: how to EDIT items 'member_name' on List with id = 001.. ?

Comment: Are you asking how to find an element in the list by its `id` and then change its `memeber_name` property?

Comment: Is `ReplyTile` a widget? Widgets should be immutable, so to change a property of the widget, you would have to rebuild the widget that contains the `ListView`. For example by calling `setState`

Comment: @JacobPhillips yes that is what i mean..

Comment: @boformer `ReplyTile` is a widget.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This assumes a `ReplyTile` is a widget, if it is not, you don't need the `setState` calls.

If you can guarantee the item is in the list, use:

```
final tile = replytile.firstWhere((item) => item.id == '001');
setState(() => tile.member_name = 'New name');
```

If the item is not found, an exception is thrown. To guard against that, use:

```
final tile = replytile.firstWhere((item) => item.id == '001', orElse: () => null);
if (tile != null) setState(() => tile.member_name = 'New name');
```

Comment: This is not a good answer if `ReplyTile` is a widget, which is what I'm suspecting from the question.

Comment: @boformer If your comment on the question is right I'm just going to leave this as is and move on.

Comment: Great it's working for me. Thank You

Answer (score 7):

Below is the code to update a single item of list using the index. You can simple create an extension function for the same.

```
extension ListUpdate<T> on List<T> {
  List<T> update(int pos, T t) {
    List<T> list = [];
    list.add(t);
    replaceRange(pos, pos + 1, list);
    return this;
  }
}
```

And use it like below to replace an item.

```
replytile.update(
    5, new ReplyTile(
        member_photo: "photo",
        member_id: "001",
        date: "01-01-2018",
        member_name: "Denis",
        id: "001",
        text: "hallo.."
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Widgets should be immutable (with final fields) and not meant to be manipulated by a parent widget.

Usually you are not supposed to store a list of widgets. Widgets should be rebuilt from scratch whenever the `build` method is called.

Instead, store the displayed data in a separate data structure (e.g. create a class `ReplyTileData`) with mutable fields. This data structure should be stored in your `State` class.

In the `build` method, read the data and instantiate your `ReplyTile` widgets with the current data.

When you want to modify the data, surround the modifying code with `setState`. This will trigger a complete rebuild (`build` called again).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a list like

```
List list =[{id=11,name=aaaa},{id=12,name=bbbb},{id=13,name=ccc}];
```

We have to find index of that object from list.

```
var data ={id=12,name=bbbb};
int index = list.indexof(data);
```

Now, you can update list

```
list[index] = {id=12,name=fffffff}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a list like

```
List list =[{id=11,name=aaaa},{id=12,name=bbbb},{id=13,name=ccc}];
```

And now you have just index data which will be update
Suppose

```
var data ={id=12,name=bbbb};
int index = list.indexof(data);
```

Now Update list as

```
list.insert(index,{id=12,name=fffffff});
```

Now output is

```
print(list);
// [{id=11,name=aaaa},{id=12,name=fffffff},{id=13,name=ccc}];
```

Comment: This will replace the element at that index and shift whatever was there below. In essence, the size of the list grow. this is incorrect.

Comment: I get this error Unhandled Exception: Unsupported operation: read-only

Comment: No, this will not work.
insert() increases the length of the list by one and shifts all objects at or after the index towards the end of the list.